# Odoo 8: How to store computed fields

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this python file

```py
class sale_order_line(models.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order.line'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('product_id')
    def _get_cost_price_currency(self):
        for lot in self:
             so_line_ids = self.env['product.product'].search([('id','=',lot.product_id.id)])
             for rec in so_line_ids:
                if rec.date_hpp_start:
                    converted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.date_hpp_start, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                    rec.days_difference = (datetime.date.today() - converted_date).days
                    if rec.days_difference > 0:
                        rec.days_difference = rec.days_difference
                    else:
                        rec.days_difference = 0
                rec.cost_price_set = rec.cost_price_set
                rec.cost_price_currency = rec.cost_price_currency
                
                if rec.currency_rate_cost2:
                    lot.currency_rate_cost = rec.currency_rate_cost2
                else:
                    lot.currency_rate_cost = rec.currency_rate_cost
                    
                lot.hpp_non_interest = rec.hpp_non_interest
                lot.date_hpp_start = rec.date_hpp_start
                lot.days_difference = rec.days_difference
                lot.interest_per_year = rec.interest_per_year
                lot.interest_per_day = rec.interest_per_year/365
                lot.interest_by_today = lot.days_difference*lot.interest_per_day
                if lot.hpp_non_interest and rec.currency_rate_cost2:
                    lot.cost_price_currency = lot.hpp_non_interest + (rec.hpp_non_interest*rec.interest_by_today/100)
                    lot.cost_price_set = lot.cost_price_currency * lot.currency_rate_cost
                elif lot.hpp_non_interest:
                    lot.cost_price_currency = '0'
                    lot.cost_price_set = rec.hpp_non_interest + (rec.hpp_non_interest*rec.interest_by_today/100)
                else:
                    lot.cost_price_currency = rec.cost_price_currency
                    lot.cost_price_set = rec.cost_price_set

    currency_rate_cost = fields.Float(string='Tax Rate',compute='_get_cost_price_currency', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Custom1') ) 
    hpp_non_interest = fields.Float(string='HPP Non Interest',compute='_get_cost_price_currency', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Custom3'))
    date_hpp_start = fields.Date(string='HPP Date start',compute='_get_cost_price_currency')
    days_difference = fields.Integer(string='Interest Age (days)', compute=_get_cost_price_currency)
    interest_per_year = fields.Float(string='Interest(%) Per Year', compute=_get_cost_price_currency)
    interest_per_day = fields.Float(string='Interest(%) Per Day', compute=_get_cost_price_currency)
    interest_by_today = fields.Float(string='Today Interest', compute=_get_cost_price_currency)
    cost_price_currency = fields.Float(string='HPP USD',compute='_get_cost_price_currency', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Custom3') ) 
    cost_price_set = fields.Float(string='Cost Price Public',compute='_get_cost_price_currency', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Custom1') )
```

and this .xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_cost_sale_order_line_form">
    <field name="name">sale.order.line.tree.cost.view.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree//field[@name='price_unit']" position="after">
            <field name="cost_price_set" />
            <field name="cost_price_currency" />
            <field name="currency_rate_cost" />
        </xpath>          
    </field>
</record>
```

I want to store the value of cost_price_set, cost_price_currency, and currency_rate_cost. The problems are:

1. If I use `store=True` in those 3 fields, the field does not update as it should
2. If I don't use `store=True`, the field is updated BUT the value does not store to the DB when click save.

What shout I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `store=True` so it will store in the database. But it will not calculate always.

It will calculate when any changes on the mentioned field in `@api.depends` as per your current code it will only change when the product id change.

So you can also mention other fields.

```
@api.depends('product_id', 'other_fields', 'product_id.product_field1')
def _get_cost_price_currency(self):
    # this is an example of how you can mention fields into depends.
```

You can also get the reference from: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/09_compute_onchange.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but when I use store=true, the field show the value from database and not from cumpute